# Loading external JS file within a vue component

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, vue-loader

I am trying to use an external js file in my .vue file but get error:

```
[Vue warn]: Method "solarSystemAnimations" has type "object" in the component definition. Did you reference the function correctly?

found in

---> <SolarSystem> at src/views/SolarSystem.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
```

I have the external js file at /src/assets/js/solarSystemAnimations:

```
export default $(window).load(function() {
  var body = $("body"),
    universe = $("#universe"),
    solarsys = $("#solar-system")

   ...
 };
```

and my .vue file looks like:

```
<template>
  <div class="solarSystem" @load="solarSystemAnimations">
    <div class="opening hide-UI view-2D zoom-large data-close controls-close">
....
</template>

<script>
import solarSystemAnimations from "@/assets/js/solarSystemAnimations.js";

export default {
  name: "SolarSystem",
  methods: {
    solarSystemAnimations: solarSystemAnimations
  }
};
</script>
```

I have looked thru numerous posts but nothing seems to work in my situation. Any help appreciated in advance.

Comment: Console.log solarSystemAnimations after importing it. You should find your mistake there. Vue is telling you it's not a function.

Comment: Ok I see solarSystemAnimations is an object in console but how can I keep it as a function? What am I not understanding thanks.

Comment: Export default function() { console.log('hello world') }. Start from there and modify.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the guidance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vue you typically use a lifecyle hook to invoke a function at a specific stage of DOM loading. Since you're referencing the window load, the Vue equivalent would be a mounted hook. You can refactor like this within the Vue component (no external file):

```
methods: {
functionBlah () {
      const body = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0],
        universe = document.getElementById("#universe"),
        solarsys = document.getElementById("#solar-system")
       ...
     }
},

mounted() {
this.functionBlah();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but I want to abstract out the function from the vue instance because of its length and complexity. That is why I want to import it.